# How a bean returned from a @Bean annotated method of a class

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm working on a Spring batch program developed by previous team a few years ago.
the main two files are as follows. the RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig class implements ItemReader interface with read() method returns null. But at the same time, the class has a @Bean method rewardsAccumulationReader() which registers a bean reading actual data to process.

I think the program uses several @Bean annotations unnecessarily as well as @Configuration on the RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig. The program does run without problem. The part that I don't understand is creating a instance of a class:

```
new RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig();
```

returns a bean registered by one of its bean method: rewardsAccumulationReader()? Isn't it true that such bean needs to be @Autowired or access via ApplicationContext?

BatchConfig.java

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchConfig {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler.cronExpression}", zone = "America/New_York")
    public void processRewardsTransactionBatchRetry() {
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID",
            REWARDS_ACCUMULATION_SERVICE.concat(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))).toJobParameters();
        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(rewardsTransactionBatchRetryJob(), param);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Job rewardsTransactionBatchRetryJob() {
        return jobs
            .get("chunksJob")
            .start(processRewardsTransaction(readerForRewardsAccumulation(), writerForRewardsAccumulation()))
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step processRewardsTransaction(ItemReader<RewardTransactionRecon> rewardsAccumulationReader,
                                      ItemWriter<RewardTransactionRecon> rewardsAccumulationWriter) {
        return steps.get("processRewardsTransaction").<RewardTransactionRecon, RewardTransactionRecon>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(rewardsAccumulationReader)
            .writer(rewardsAccumulationWriter)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

    @Bean(name = "rewardsAccumulationReader")
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<RewardTransactionRecon> readerForRewardsAccumulation() {
        return new RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig();
}

    @Bean(name = "rewardsAccumulationWriter")
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<RewardTransactionRecon> writerForRewardsAccumulation() {
        return new RewardsAccumulationWriterConfig();
    }
}
```

// RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig implements ItemReader<RewardTransactionRecon> {
    ....
    @Bean(name = "rewardsAccumulationReader")
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<RewardTransactionRecon> rewardsAccumulationReader(@Qualifier("azureDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
        ...
        return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<RewardTransactionRecon>()
            .name("RewardsAccumulationReader")
            .dataSource(datasource)
            .queryProvider(queryProvider)
            .parameterValues(parameter)
            .sortKeys(Collections.singletonMap("event_id", Order.ASCENDING))
            .rowMapper(buildRowMapper())
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public RewardTransactionRecon read() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can return any class from a @Bean method and it gets registered as a bean.

Comment: My question was why "new RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig();" returns the rewardsAccumulationReader bean instead of a RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig object with null read() implementation?

Comment: how would we know lol? That's your code. Nothing to do with Java or Spring.

Comment: I meant "new RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig();" should return a RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig object where read() is implemented as returning null. while the rewardsAccumulationReader bean is only registered with container, to use it, it has to be @Autowired or access through ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 1):

you're right there are a few mistakes.

1 - RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig shouldn't be implementing ItemReader as it's a simple @Configuration class registering an ItemReader bean.
Remove that and also remove the method read() from it. Btw, this explains why the method readerForRewardsAccumulation() from BatchConfig is returning an ItemReader.

2 - Remove the method readerForRewardsAccumulation() from BatchConfig, the only time one would need to register RewardsAccumulationReaderConfig as a bean is when the latter is not visible to component scanning.

3 - Same story for the method writerForRewardsAccumulation (remove it).

Good luck.

Comment: I agree. But the code works as it is (read() returns null) without problem. How can we explain that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).